# Convert object into JSON

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm trying convert next variables into JSON

```
class RHypervisor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.label = "hv01"

    this.state = {
      hypervisor_type: "xen",
      cpu_units: 2250,
      hypervisor_group_label: "kvm_hvz_1",
      hardware_configs: {
        vsphere: {}
    }
  }
}

var myMap = new Map().set(this.label, this.state)

console.log(myMap)
```

Code work fine, but I can't get JSON which I need, in the next format:

```
{
   "hv01": {
      "cpu_units": "2250",
      "hypervisor_group_label": "kvm_hvz_1",
      "hardware_configs": {
        "vsphere": {...}
      }
   }
}
```

I got in console:

```
[
  "hv01",
    {
      "hypervisor_type": "xen",
      "cpu_units": 2250,
      "hypervisor_group_label": "kvm_hvz_1",
      "hardware_configs": {
        "vsphere": {...}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How I can get top level key as `this.label` and next object `this.state`

PS. I'm totally new in JS only few days work with this... please help me in this question

Comment: You do realize JSON and Map are 2 different things right? By JSON, we normally mean a string that can be deserialized into JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Map.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("hv01", {
  hypervisor_type: "xen",
  cpu_units: 2250,
  hypervisor_group_label: "kvm_hvz_1",
  hardware_configs: {
    vsphere: {}
  }
});

console.log(Object.fromEntries([...myMap.entries()]));
```

Explanation:

`[...myMap.entries()]` returns an array of key-value pairs (`[["hv01", { ... }]]`) and `Object.fromEntries()` creates a new object with those key-value pairs.